# How to setup django with lighttpd?

Tags: django, gunicorn, uwsgi, lighttpd

I have a live website that is running under lighttpd. I now have a sub-domain that I want to run under django. I do not want to move to Apache as I don't currently have the resources to support two production web servers. The django part is actually working well with the django builtin development server so now I just need to port it into production.

It seems that all documentation to setup django with lighttpd is over 10 years old and uses fastcgi that from what I can see was deprecated and removed from django. The new docs point to use wscgi - scgi under lighttpd. But even that is being hard to get any documentation.

Do I need to run uwsgi and use that to serve the pages to mod_scgi? Or should I use gunicorn? I am sort of at a loss on what to do.

Suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lighttpd supports uwsgi with [mod_scgi](https://wiki.lighttpd.net/mod_scgi) and `scgi.protocol = "uwsgi"`

```
scgi.protocol = "uwsgi"
scgi.server = ( "/" =>
    (
        (
            "socket" => "/tmp/scgi.sock",
            "check-local" => "disable",
            "fix-root-scriptname" => "enable"
        )
    )
)
```

Using [mod_scgi](https://wiki.lighttpd.net/mod_scgi) and the uwsgi protocol to communicate with the Django server will likely be faster and use fewer resources than using gunicorn (and communicating using lighttpd [mod_proxy](https://wiki.lighttpd.net/mod_proxy))

[How to use Django with uWSGI](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/uwsgi/)

The uWSGI docs linked there recommend configuring the web server to serve static files rather than sending those requests to Django.

Comment: I actually ended up using this solution and it works. However, there is a URL issue that I added [as another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75243888/problem-serving-django-polls-tutorial-under-lighttpd-404-page-not-found)

Comment: I updated the example to include `"fix-root-scriptname" => "enable"`.  [RFC3875 PATH_INFO](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875.html#section-4.1.5)  With `"check-local" => "disable"` lighttpd is unable to determine where PATH_INFO begins by checking the local path, as checking the local path is disabled by `"check-local" => "disable"`