# Problem serving Django "polls" tutorial under lighttpd: 404 page not found

Tags: python, django, uwsgi, lighttpd

I am following the Django polls tutorial, which is working 100% with the built-in development server (`python3 manage.py runserver`).

I have set up lighttpd to serve django through UWSGI and that seems to be working fine but for one glitch: the URL passed to django seems to have been modified.

My lighttpd configuration is basically this:

```
...
server.modules += ("mod_scgi","mod_rewrite")
scgi.protocol = "uwsgi"
scgi.server   = (
    "/polls" => ((
             "host" => "localhost",
             "port" => 7000,
             "check-local" => "disable",
    ))
)
```

The Django tutorial mapping looks like:

```py
# tutorial1/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

# polls/urls.py
app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/results/', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

However when I hit `http://localhost:8080/polls/` in the address bar, it produces an 404 error.

[image]

If I add an extra `/polls` to the URL then it works just fine.

[image]

[image]

My goal with this exercise is to be able to serve this app switching from and to both servers without needing to modify configuration files each time.

What do I need to do on the `lighttpd.conf` side to make lighttpd interchangeable with Django's own internal dev server?

I have tried to add the following `url.rewrite` rule but it messes up completely the URL handling.

```
url.rewrite = (
    "^/polls/(.*)$" => "/polls/polls/$1"
)
```

With the URL rewrite, the first call `http://127.0.0.1/polls/` works fine but the links to the detail posts are generated as `http://127.0.0.1/polls/polls/1` and the resulting sub-url `polls/1` is not recognized by the `polls/urls.py` settings.

Using the empty path in lighttpd server:

```
    scgi.protocol = "uwsgi"
    scgi.server   = (
        "" => ((
                 "host" => "localhost",
                 "port" => 7000,
                 "check-local" => "disable",
        ))
    )
```

Produces this very weird result:
[image]

The `Raised by: polls.views.DetailView` means that the URL is actually being parsed and forwarded correctly to the Polls Detail view, which is 100% the correct handler, but it is somehow raising a 404? WTF

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated [here](https://woof.sourceforge.net/woof-ug-0.5/_woof/docs/ug/lighttpd_scgi)

> The setting of the variable `fix-root-scriptname` is required for some versions of Lighttpd to fix a bug in Lighttpd when it is running a SCGI server rooted at /.

```
scgi.server   = (
    "/" => ((
             "host" => "localhost",
             "port" => 7000,
             "check-local" => "disable",
             "fix-root-scriptname" => "enable",
    ))
```

---

Previous answer:

Have you tried using an empty string? (It's a not a proper answer to the question but I can't make a comment)

Comment: With the empty string nothing works: `127.0.0.1/polls` nor `127.0.0.1/polls/polls`. With the root `"/"` string only `127.0.0.1/polls/polls` works. I do not understand how this URL is being handled.

Comment: I updated the post with more results from your suggestion.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with lighttpd.
Is there a reason you need to use lighthttpd? You can quite easily run it with uWSGI:
pip install uwsgi
`uwsgi --http :9090 --wsgi-file yourapp/wsgi.py`
that's all

Comment: I am actually running `uwsgi` to serve Django to lighttpd. The main reason is security as there are many (geo)security and spam control features already configured in lighttpd. Also I want lighttpd to serve static files as it is more efficient.